# R: Sorting with a predetermined order

Tags: r, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

2,39  1
1,94  3
1,71  4
1,48  2

I'd like to sort to have a result like this:

2,39
1,71
1,48
1,94

Meaning that I first take the first element in the first column, then the third one, then the fourth one, ...

I first thought of using the apply function on the second column like this:

```
apply(... , sort)
apply(... , rev)
```

But doing so, I get:

2,39
1,48
1,94
1,71

I can have the desired result if I use a for loop but I wondered if there was a way to do this by using the apply function, which gives a cleaner code.

Comment: Check the `match` function.

Comment: It looks that you, simply, need to subset the first column with the seond one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple indexing?

```
data <- data.frame(1:4)
data[, c(1,3,4,2)]
```

Comment: Your code will throw an error if df is a data.frame. You want `data[c(1,3,4,2),]`.

Comment: thx for the hint. He was asking for columns of a data frame so we have to combine our answers, see the edit :) Thanks anyway!